# Simulating WAves Nearshore and the use of triangle.

Tags: cygwin, c

Hei, I'm trying to get into SWAN and triangle, while not having any coding experience and I'm having a hard time since following designated guides do not give results. Does anybody have any idea how to use them?

SWAN questions:

- Is there a way to read input file with extension .swn? So that I can analyze test files.
- How to connect files with different extensions, is the .swn file responsible for it?
- How to post-process data? I guess that triangle does it? Many documents show figures of bathymetries with computed wave heights.

I probably misunderstood a lot.

As for triangle, I've been having issues just running this program. 
I believe that I compiled it correctly (followed many guides), and I got a .exe file in the directory. I still cannot use the commands to run a mesh, or just to get a figure like said in its own guide.

Comments in "makefile"

makefile for Triangle and Show Me

Type "make" to compile Triangle and Show Me.

After compiling, type "triangle -h" and "showme -h" to read instructions for using each of these programs.

It says to simply type "make" and stuff. 
For example, I'm trying to run the sample file A.poly. The command promt tells me that a command "triangle" is not found. 
I don't know what to do, why can't some things just work ;D

I'm using Cygwin64 terminal for triangle and SWAN got its own on win10. 
I installed gcc and stuff on cygwin.

If someone got a good tutorial for dummies, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The site did not allow me to create a SWAN and triangle tab. :(

Comment: Have you read the Manual http://swanmodel.sourceforge.net/online_doc/swanuse/swanuse.html ?

Comment: Ye, I did. Got it all printed. It says that the .edt file is all written as a comment, so I guess that I need to delete "!". Then changing of variables? Example; Friction part in .edt. do I just leave JONSWAP as a whole and delete the rest? The manual explains well all of the functions. And the test files don't even involve the commands from .edt, it is all just confusing.

Comment: Than the place to ask for help is the user mailing list https://sourceforge.net/p/swanmodel/mailman/

Comment: I did not know this exists. I'm gonna go through every message, there might actually be hope after all ;D Thank you.